# Seeding pivot table, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Tags: laravel

I am trying to seed a pivot table named 'reseller_products' but Laravel seems to be inserting a wrong value in the 'product_id' column and I can't figure out why. The error I recieve is:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Address of the website of the reseller' for column `test`.`reseller_products`.`product_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `reseller_products` (`product_id`, `reseller_id`) values (Address of the website of the reseller, 1))
```

My Database seeder class:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Reseller;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $product = Product::create([
            'name' => 'Name of the product',
            'price' => 9.99
        ]);

        $reseller = Reseller::create([
            'name' => 'Name of the reseller',
            'url' => 'Address of the website of the reseller'
        ]);

        $reseller->products()->attach($product->id);

    }
}
```

My relations:

My Product model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Reseller;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

        /**
     * The resellers that belong to the Products
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function resellers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Reseller::class, 'reseller_products', 'product_id', 'reseller_id', 'url', 'selector', 'price');
    }

}
```

My Reseller model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Product;

class Reseller extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The products that belong to the Reseller
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'reseller_products', 'product_id', 'reseller_id', 'url', 'selector', 'price');
    }

}
```

*IGNORE* Some dummy text because I get an error I need to add more rext

Comment: please add your product and reseller models to questions

Comment: You only need to specify the table name and related fields in your relationship method (if they do not follow convention), the other fields are not required.

Comment: @Peppermintology Thanks, I didn't know that!